# Warning when computing Cohen's kappa with psych

Tags: r, psych

In my `db` dataframe, I compute a score by 2 ways as `scoreA` and `scoreB`. I then get their quintiles, and I want to get the Cohen's kappa coefficient between them.

I found several libraries in the CRAN, and `psych` seemed the most used one, but I'm open to other possibilities.

Here is some code to test :

```
set.seed(1)
df=data.frame(
  scoreA = rnorm(n = 200, mean = 1, sd = .75)*10,
  scoreB = rnorm(n = 200, mean = 5, sd = 3)*10
)
df$quintA = cut(df$scoreA, breaks=quantile(df$scoreA, probs=seq(0,1, by=0.2), na.rm = TRUE), labels=c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5"), include.lowest = T)
df$quintB = cut(df$scoreB, breaks=quantile(df$scoreB, probs=seq(0,1, by=0.2), na.rm = TRUE), labels=c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5"), include.lowest = T)
plot(df$quintA, df$quintB, xlab="A", ylab="B")
psych::cohen.kappa(table(df$quintA, df$quintB))

Call: cohen.kappa1(x = x, w = w, n.obs = n.obs, alpha = alpha, levels = levels)

Cohen Kappa and Weighted Kappa correlation coefficients and confidence boundaries 
                  lower estimate upper
unweighted kappa -0.058    0.012 0.083 #My real world estimates are about 0.5
weighted kappa   -0.215   -0.070 0.075

 Number of subjects = 200 
Warning message:
In any(abs(bounds)) : coercing argument of type 'double' to logical
```

Should I be worried about the warning ? What does it mean ?

EDIT : I just tried with `fmsb` and get the exact same values than for the unweighted kappa (even for decimals). The question still goes on in case there is a problem with the wheighted kappa.

```
library(fmsb)
Kappa.test(db$scoreA, db$scoreB)
$Result

    Estimate Cohen kappa statistics and test the null hypothesis that the
    extent of agreement is same as random (kappa=0)

data:  db$scoreA and db$scoreB
Z = 383.67, p-value < 2.2e-16
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.9077865 0.9131626
sample estimates:
[1] 0.9104745

$Judgement
[1] "Almost perfect agreement"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not worry about your results. The warning you are getting occurs because your data is numeric and `psych::cohen.kappa` expects logical, so it tries to coerce it from the original data type to the one it needs.

Consider the following. We are creating a data frame with simulated data from two scales. The possible values in the scales are 0 and 1. Then we run `cohen.kappa` and `Kappa.test`.

```
set.seed(1984)
db <- data.frame(
  scoreA = rbinom(n = 20, size = 1, prob = .75),
  scoreB = rbinom(n = 20, size = 1, prob = .75)
)

# psych
cohen.kappa(table(db$scoreA, db$scoreB))

Call: cohen.kappa1(x = x, w = w, n.obs = n.obs, alpha = alpha, levels = levels)

Cohen Kappa and Weighted Kappa correlation coefficients and confidence boundaries 
                 lower estimate  upper
unweighted kappa -0.37    -0.21 -0.048
weighted kappa   -0.37    -0.21 -0.048

 Number of subjects = 20 
Warning message:
In any(abs(bounds)) : coercing argument of type 'double' to logical


# fmsb
Kappa.test(db$scoreA, db$scoreB)
$Result

    Estimate Cohen's kappa statistics and test the null hypothesis that the extent of
    agreement is same as random (kappa=0)

data:  db$scoreA and db$scoreB
Z = -0.59134, p-value = 0.7229
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.9277148  0.5139217
sample estimates:
[1] -0.2068966


$Judgement
[1] "No agreement"
```

Results are pretty much the same. This is because the coercion was succesful. It did happen like this:

```
# Original    
db$scoreA
     [1] 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1
# Coerced
    as.logical(db$scoreA)
     [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
    [16]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

The warning is just telling you what it happened and as long as you coding is consistent between scales, there souldn't be any problem at all.

Comment: Thank you, your point was very clear. So based on what you say, it seems that I don't need a Cohen's kappa, since my score is not binary. What would you recommand then ?

Comment: After some research, it seems possible to use the Cohen's kappa for non binary score, as described [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Statistical_analysis/Inter-rater_reliability). So if `db$scoreA=c(0,5,9,7,3,5,2,6,0,2)` it should'nt have to be coersed to logical, isn't it ?